# SQL Server Procedure or function CreateTable has too many arguments specified

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a table with 2 columns: Name of the customer of type varchar and age of type int.

My code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateTable 
    (@tablename varchar(50), 
     @column varchar(50),
     @type varchar(50),
     @column2 varchar(20), 
     @type2 int, 
     @extra varchar(20) = NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sqlQuery AS varchar(MAX)
    SET @sqlQuery = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @tablename +  '( id int '+ @column +' ' + @type + @column2 +' ' + @type2+'  PRIMARY KEY(id))'

    PRINT (@sqlQuery)
    EXEC (@sqlQuery)
END
GO

EXEC CreateTable 'Customers', 'Name', 'varchar(50)', 'Age', 'int'
```

The error is:

> Procedure or function CreateTable has too many arguments specified

I don't know where my error is. Please help me.

Comment: I don't get that error:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3ef97770acb69929cc61a4033aa00e29.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be OK now:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateTable (
    @tablename VARCHAR(50)
    ,@column VARCHAR(50)
    ,@type VARCHAR(50)
    ,@column2 VARCHAR(20)
    ,@type2 VARCHAR(50)
    ,@extra VARCHAR(20) = NULL
    )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sqlQuery AS VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @sqlQuery = 'create table ' + @tablename + '( id int ,' + @column + '  ' + @type + ' , ' + @column2 + ' ' + @type2 + '  PRIMARY KEY(id))'

    PRINT (@sqlQuery)

    EXEC (@sqlQuery)
END
GO

EXEC CreateTable 'Customers'
    ,'Name'
    ,'varchar(50)'
    ,'Age'
    ,'int'
```

If you compare the parameters you will find the type of `@type2` was specified as `int` while it should be `varchar` to be part of the executed statement.

You were also missing comma`(,)` in your executable string inside the stored procedure.